# Is it possible to send an SMS with hyperlink and anchor text (hidden URL) on Android device?

Tags: android, hyperlink, sms

I know that the Android Message app can parse URLs that starts with "www" and "http://", making them hyperlinks. But is it possible to send a hyperlink, where only the anchor text is displayed and the URL is hidden?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, no, you can't.

SMS is a specific standard that contains just text. So when you send something that looks like a URL, the Android (and iOS/Windows/whatever) messaging apps can detect it using a RegEx or similar and make it a link. But you can't do anything like an `<a href="">` tag as you would with HTML. You might be able to use MMS to achieve this, but I'm not 100% on that.

Good luck!